# Vaadin multi column calendar

Tags: calendar, vaadin, multiple-columns

I'm currently developing an web application with Vaadin 7.6 and java 8, where I have to display a calendar for several entities. 
It should look like the schedule in the vaadin dashboard demo (https://demo.vaadin.com/dashboard/#!schedule), just not for multiple days but multiple entities.

It could look like this:
[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYRLz.png)

I looked at the Calendar class from vaadin, but I don't know where to start to get the desired behavior.
Does someone have an idea where to start?

Comment: Beside the Calendar add on, you can also buit it yourself with for example the grid component.

Comment: So you think its easier to customize a Grid instead customize the Calendar?

Comment: It depends on what you will need. The GridLayout is very flexible, but you will have to do everything yourself. The Calendar add on "knows" about Dates, so that part would be solved for you. But I'm not sure it supports multiple Columns per date

Comment: No, the calendar component doesn't support multiple columns per date, but the grid does not support merging cells, which I would need for events with variable duration. The problem is, that I didn't found something similarly on the web, so I don't know if its even possible. I looked at the Extending components  [blog entry](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/2656782), but I just don't find a point to start the customization :(

Comment: I was talking about the `GridLayout`, not the `Grid` component! The `GridLayout`allows you to merge cells https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-gridlayout.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the `GridLayout`. I personally like the appearance of the calendar, so I decided to customize the `Calendar` from the client and the server side. I added the multiple column feature and made it an `DragSource` so `Events`can also be dragged out of the calendar. When I finished the work on this I will probably release this as an addon.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use: [Vaadin Calendar Add On](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/vaadin-calendar).

Check an online demo at: http://demo.vaadin.com/calendar

Comment: The Calendar Add On is now integrated in Vaadin. It is the Calendar class I wrote about.